# Number of bins for discretization

Tags: data-transformation, continuous-data, discrete-data, data-preprocessing, binning

How do I decide on the right number of bins to discretize my continuous data? Are there are tests/techniques to do the same? Could someone give me some idea into existing approaches?

Comment: Why do you want to use discretization at all?

Comment: Because, I have to compute a metric called conditional entropy rate which can only be done on discrete data.

Comment: Why do you have to compute a metric that relies on discretization? Discretization is almost always a bad idea: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/1352 If your KPI requires it, it would be a good idea to find out *why* that KPI should be used.

Comment: What is your purpose? Can you say what kind of data you have?